# PHP use MYSQL table result as parameter for another query

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a table on my site that is pulled from MYSQL based on a search. I would like to be able to click a button added to the table which opens a modal with more data based on the row selected. In the below image I have a column labeled ID for the first table, which could be used for the  = ? in my query, but I do not know how to set the value as a parameter first. Any thoughts on the best way to go about this?

I have `$term = '%' . $_GET['itemID'] . '%';` added for the second query but need a way to bind ID 999999, 1000000, or 1000001 based on the corresponding view button. Thanks!

[image: First Table]

```
if(isset($_GET['term']))
    {   
       
        $term = '%' . $_GET['term'] . '%';
        $sql1 = "SELECT ID, Source, Contract_Number, Price_Effective, Price_Expiration, Min_Price, Average_Price
        FROM Both_Search WHERE SearchName LIKE ? LIMIT 10";

        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql1); 
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $term);   
        $stmt->execute();
        $result1 = $stmt->get_result();
          while($row1 = $result1->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "<td>" . $row1["ID"] . "</td>"; <----would want this to be the parameter for next query
            echo "<td>" . $row1["Source"] . "</td>";
            echo "<td><a target='_blank' rel='noopener noreferrer' href='contracts.php?number=" . $row1["Contract_Number"] . "'>" . $row1["Contract_Number"] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row1["Price_Effective"] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row1["Price_Expiration"] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . "$ " . $row1["Average_Price"] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . "$ " . $row1["Min_Price"] . "</td>"; ?>
                <td><button id="myBtn" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">View</button></td>
            </tr><?php

             }
            }
            
      
            
         
?> 

</tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>


                <!-- The Modal -->
                <div id="myModal" class="modal">


<!-- Modal content -->
<div class="modal-content">
  <span class="close">&times;</span>

  <div class="card shadow mb-4">
    <div class="card-header py-3" style="background-color: rgb(90, 136, 255);">
        <h6 class="m-0 font-weight-bold text-white">Tiers</h6>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-bordered" id="dataTable2" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Price 1</th>
                        <th>Price 2</th>
                        <th>Price 3</th>
                        <th>Price 4</th>
                        <th>Price 5</th>
                        <th>Price 6</th>
                        <th>Price 7</th>
                        <th>Price 8</th>
                        <th>Price 9</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>

                            <tbody>
                            
                                                                      
                                                                      <?php
                                                                      
                                                                        
                                                                      if(isset($_GET['itemID']))
                                                                          {   
                                                                             
                                                                              $term = '%' . $_GET['itemID'] . '%';
                                                                              $sql1 = "SELECT *
                                                                              FROM Pricelist WHERE ID = ? LIMIT 10";
                                                                      
                                                                              $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql1); 
                                                                              $stmt->bind_param("s", $term);   
                                                                              $stmt->execute();
                                                                              $result1 = $stmt->get_result();
                                                                                while($row1 = $result1->fetch_assoc()) {
                                                                                  echo "<td>" . "$ " . $row1["P_1"] . "</td>";
                                                                                  echo "<td>" . "$ " . $row1["P_2"] . "</td>";
                                                                                  echo "<td>" . "$ " . $row1["P_3"] . "</td>";
                                                                                  echo "<td>" . "$ " . $row1["P_4"] . "</td>";
                                                                                  echo "<td>" . "$ " . $row1["P_5"] . "</td>";
                                                                                  echo "<td>" . "$ " . $row1["P_6"] . "</td>";
                                                                                  echo "<td>" . "$ " . $row1["P_7"] . "</td>";
                                                                                  echo "<td>" . "$ " . $row1["P_8"] . "</td>";
                                                                                  echo "<td>" . "$ " . $row1["P_9"] . "</td>";
                                                                                  
                                                                                  ?>
                                                                                    </tr> <?php
                                                                                   }
                                                                                  }
                                                                                  
                                                                                  $conn->close();
                                                                                  
                                                                         
                                                                      ?> 
                                                                             
                                                                      </tbody>  
<script>
    // Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on the button, open the modal
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}


</script>
```

Comment: You have two ways to do it. 1. If you want to use $_GET than replace button with <a> and put link in like table_details.php?id=4 and than use $_GET['item_id'] on table_details.php. 2. Use javascript and AJAX to open modal and fetch item_id. On a button add data-id=4 fetch it with javascript, pass it to php file to get the result and display modal on success.

Comment: @BudimirSkrtic Sorry I am not sure I fully get it, still learning. I just added the script I'm using to my code above. Both the main table and modal table are in a file names Search2.php So should I change the button to this? `<td><a search2.php?ID=4 id="myBtn" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">View</button></td>`

Answer (score 2):

You got the ID as `$row1["ID"]` and you can use that ID for **Another Query**.

```
// Replace this
<td><button id="myBtn" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">View</button></td>
// To this
<td><a href="YOUR_PAGE_VIEW.php?id=<?= $row1["ID"]; ?>" id="myBtn"  class="btn btn-primary">View</a></td>
```

And the button 'View' will redirect to YOUR_PAGE_VIEW.php with the Param Query ID = $row1["ID"].
Now you have the ID as variable `$id` for **Another Query** what you want in the YOU_PAGE_VIEW.php.

```
// In YOUR_PAGE_VIEW.php
$id = $_GET['id'];
```

Hope this help you,

Comment: Thank you! That seems to get me partially where I am looking. Works correctly to get the $id into the new query. Only issue I am having is that it opens in another page instead of a modal in the same page.  I'm thinking I will have to use AJAX somehow to keep it all on the same page

Comment: Yes, you can use AJAX for update the data & UI what you want.